# Glitchy character animation- pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a duplicate of the [Chrome dinosaur game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinosaur_Game) in `pygame`. So far, I've added the dinosaur sprite and its animations, along with the background. The sprite animations aren't working smoothly. I've been trying to fix this for a while now, with no luck. I haven't detected what causes this issue yet. Can anyone help me find the part that's making the game glitchy along with helping me fix it? Code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Dinosaur Game")
walk1_image = pygame.image.load("images/walk1.png")
walk1 = pygame.transform.scale(walk1_image, (64, 64))
bend_image = pygame.image.load("images/bend.png")
bend = pygame.transform.scale(bend_image, (64, 64))
walk2_image = pygame.image.load("images/walk2.png")
walk2 = pygame.transform.scale(walk2_image, (64, 64))
die_image = pygame.image.load("images/die.png")
die = pygame.transform.scale(die_image, (64, 64))
jump_image = pygame.image.load("images/jump.png")
jump = pygame.transform.scale(jump_image, (64, 64))

images_list = [walk1, walk2, die, jump, bend]
floor_image = pygame.image.load("images/floor-0.png").convert()
floor = pygame.transform.scale(floor_image, (500, 100))
bgX = 0
bgX2 = floor.get_width()
ADD_event = pygame.event.Event(pygame.USEREVENT+1)
pygame.event.post(ADD_event)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def game_intro():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        WINDOW.fill("#FFFFFF")
        my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 40)
        label = my_font.render("Press space to play", True, "#696969")
        WINDOW.blit(jump, (125, 200))
        WINDOW.blit(label, (125, 300))
        pygame.display.update()
        for event2 in pygame.event.get():
            keys2 = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if event2.type == pygame.QUIT or keys2[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
                intro = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if keys2[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                intro = False
                return


class Dino(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dino, self).__init__()
        self.images = []
        self.images.append(walk1)
        self.images.append(walk2)
        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.x = 200
        self.y = 323

    def update(self):
        WINDOW.blit(floor, (bgX, 300))
        WINDOW.blit(floor, (bgX2, 300))
        self.index += 1
        if self.index >= len(self.images):
            self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        WINDOW.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
        pygame.display.update()


def draw():
    WINDOW.fill("#FFFFFF")
    pygame.display.update()


def start():
    start_image = pygame.image.load("images/start.png")
    start = pygame.transform.scale(start_image, (150, 50))
    WINDOW.blit(start, (175, 225))
    pygame.display.update()


game_intro()
speed = 32
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 1000)
run = True
my_sprite = Dino()
my_group = pygame.sprite.Group(my_sprite)
while run:
    clock.tick(speed)
    bgX -= 0.2
    bgX2 -= 0.2
    if bgX < floor.get_width() * -1:
        bgX = floor.get_width()
    if bgX2 < floor.get_width() * -1:
        bgX2 = floor.get_width()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            speed += 10

    draw()
    my_group.update()

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Inside the `images` directory:

bend.png:

[image: bend.png]

die.png:

[image: die.png]

floor-0.png (background):
[image: floor-0.png]

jump.png:

[image: jump.png]

walk1.png:

[image: walk1.png]

walk2.png:

[image: walk2.png]

@Chaos_is_Harmony ended up helping me. (a big thanks to him). We talked in chat and fixed the issue. Updated code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Dinosaur Game")
walk1_image = pygame.image.load("images/walk1.png")
walk1 = pygame.transform.scale(walk1_image, (64, 64))
bend_image = pygame.image.load("images/bend.png")
bend = pygame.transform.scale(bend_image, (64, 64))
walk2_image = pygame.image.load("images/walk2.png")
walk2 = pygame.transform.scale(walk2_image, (64, 64))
die_image = pygame.image.load("images/die.png")
die = pygame.transform.scale(die_image, (64, 64))
jump_image = pygame.image.load("images/jump.png")
jump = pygame.transform.scale(jump_image, (64, 64))

images_list = [walk1, walk2, die, jump, bend]
floor_image = pygame.image.load("images/floor-0.png").convert()
floor = pygame.transform.scale(floor_image, (500, 100))
bgX = 0
bgX2 = floor.get_width()

def game_intro():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        WINDOW.fill("#FFFFFF")
        my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 40)
        label = my_font.render("Press space to play", True, "#696969")
        WINDOW.blit(jump, (125, 200))
        WINDOW.blit(label, (125, 300))
        pygame.display.update()
        for event2 in pygame.event.get():
            keys2 = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if event2.type == pygame.QUIT or keys2[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
                intro = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if keys2[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                intro = False
                return


class Dino(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dino, self).__init__()
        self.images = []
        self.images.append(walk1)
        self.images.append(walk2)
        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.x = 200
        self.y = 323

    def update(self):
        WINDOW.blit(floor, (bgX, 300))
        WINDOW.blit(floor, (bgX2, 300))
        self.index += 1
        if self.index >= len(self.images):
            self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        WINDOW.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
        pygame.display.update()


def draw():
    WINDOW.fill("#FFFFFF")
    pygame.display.update()


def start():
    start_image = pygame.image.load("images/start.png")
    start = pygame.transform.scale(start_image, (150, 50))
    WINDOW.blit(start, (175, 225))
    pygame.display.update()


game_intro()
speed = 32
run = True
my_sprite = Dino()
my_group = pygame.sprite.Group(my_sprite)
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    bgX -= 2
    bgX2 -= 2
    if bgX < floor.get_width() * -1:
        bgX = floor.get_width()
    if bgX2 < floor.get_width() * -1:
        bgX2 = floor.get_width()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    draw()
    my_group.update()
```

Comment: I'm guessing you tried adjusting the speed variable already, correct?

Comment: @Chaos_Is_Harmony, yes

Comment: I'm also not seeing any key mappings other than for bending, so it's the bend animation that's wonky?

Comment: Also, where is ```dino_stat.bend_dino()``` defined? I can't find it. Or even just ```dino_stat``` for that matter...

Comment: @Chaos_Is_Harmony, the problem is with the walking. Sometimes the dinosaur changes animations very fast and other times very slowly

Comment: @Chaos_Is_Harmony, `dino_stat.bend_dino()` is an old part I forgot to delete

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236350/discussion-between-chaos-is-harmony-and-roni).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it the bg movement seems tied to the animation, changing the values for

```
bgX -= 0.2
bgX2 -= 0.2
```

Would probably help.

And also removing one of the two calls to update the display would aid performance.